# Netplan configuration problems in Ubuntu Server 22.10

Tags: networking, server, netplan, 22.10

I have problems with netplan in Ubuntu Server 22.10. IPv4 network not working (after reboot).
Here is my netplan config:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens3:
     dhcp4: false
     dhcp6: false
     addresses: [45.80.XX.XX/32, 2a03:XXXX:85::5ba/125]
     nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 2606:4700:4700::1111, 2001:4860:4860::888]
     routes:
     - to: 0.0.0.0/0 # default IPv4 route
       via: 10.0.0.1
     - to: ::/0 # default IPv6 route
       via: 2a03:XXXX:85::5b9
  version: 2
```

(My gateway IPv4: 10.0.0.1, My address IPv4: 45.80.XX.XX/32) (My gateway IPv6: 2a03:XXXX:85::5b9; subnet: 2a03:XXXX:85::5b8/125; My address: 2a03:XXXX:85::5ba/125)

Situation is now, that IPv6 work, but IPv4 no…

When I am manually add this:

`sudo ip route add 10.0.0.1 dev ens3`

all net works (IPv4, IPv6), but before reboot! After reboot (or applying Netplan config) IPv4 not work…

So, after reboot I see:

```
# ip neigh
1.1.1.1 dev ens3 FAILED
8.8.8.8 dev ens3 FAILED
fe80::fc54::XX:XXXX:1904 dev ens3 lladdr 02:00:00:00:00:01 router REACHABLE
2a03:XXXX:85::5b9 dev ens3 lladdr 02:00:00:00:00:01 router REACHABLE
```

Question:
How I can add this route to Netplan permanently:

`sudo ip route add 10.0.0.1 dev ens3`

and how to delete this incorrect strings:

```
1.1.1.1 dev ens3 FAILED
8.8.8.8 dev ens3 FAILED
```

Comment: No, 10.0.0.1 - its my gateway (for IPv4). IPv4 is working for me, but IPv6 no... P.S. 45.80.XX.XX/32 - it` my IPv4 dedicated IP address.

Comment: What documentation did the service provider give you about the IPv6 network?  I see several things that are suspect here - overlapping network declarations; two local IP addresses declared where one is a network address instead of a host address; use of `on-link` where it's not necessary - but no one can tell you the "right" configuration for your server without knowing how your provider has configured the network.

Comment: What does “not working” mean? Does a ping to the default GW work?  
Is your default gateway your internet router at IPv6? Does the default GW advertise any IPv6 network? Is the IPv6 network I use officially assigned to you?

Comment: The current situation with the network has changed a bit.